# Javascript: How to verify if an entry is empty but at the same time verify that it does not insert empty spaces?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="api_crud_form" name="api_crud_form" action="https://www.google.es">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#api_crud_form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#name').val() == '') {
                alert("enter name");
            } 
            else{
              alert("the data was sent");
            }
    });
  });

</script>
```

> Here is an example

**This is a valid example if the field is empty but not valid if you insert an empty space**

> As you can see in the example sending empty spaces

Comment: Please post in English, or to post in Spanish use https://es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="api_crud_form" name="api_crud_form" action="https://www.google.es">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#api_crud_form').on('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#name').val().trim() == '') {
                alert("enter name");
            } 
            else{
              alert("the data was sent");
            }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: thansk friends served me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()`:

```
if ($('#name').val().trim() == '') {
```